# Excel multiple criteria match with partial strings using formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data that I would like to assign a description based on the partial strings as those can come with partial and different names. Below is an example of the column I need to add a description next to based on the partial match:

```
PRODUCT
ARK-78787
7878ARK-7555
BEL*EEER44
eerBEL*/*
fdseebel***
```

and I have a table like this for the description

```
Category A  ARK,BAR,CER
Category B  BEL,CEL,DEL
```

I need to match those multiple strings while checking the partial match but have no luck so far. The formula I'm using is:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($G$3:$I$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2:$I$2,B2))),1))
```

Attaching a Google Sheets file as a reference to have a better picture of this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QuJ695jd4fcZrVdjHEFZa9T7F5c1Ky2xCCzspu8FAiw/edit?usp=sharing

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the formula in D2 as an array formula and drag it down

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$5,MAX((ROW($I$2:$K$5)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$2:$K$5,A2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided non-array-formula and sample data, the final formula would look like

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$5,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($I$2:$K$5))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$2:$K$5,A2))),1))
```

EDIT: set ranges according to the answer of @usmanhaq.

[image]